# Getting sunset times at location with only UTC timezone

Tags: php, math, gis

I have the following inputs:

- Departure and arrival place (coordinates).
- Departure time and arrival time (in UTC).

My problem: Say I have a flight from a certain location to another location, I am trying to calculate the amount of time that flight happened after sunset. What I have done so far is to get coordinates at a set interval between point A and B (1 minute apart).

I am then using PHP's date_sun_info to get the sunset time at that location but the times are all wrong. How can I handle timezones properly as I suspect this is the issue.

what I have tried so far is:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$deptime= new DateTime($flightdate.' '.$flightdep); //2020-09-22 11:00
...
...  
    // Get coordinates between the two points using PHPGEO and loop:

        foreach ($coords as $value) { // loop through coordinates               
            $sunset = date_sun_info(strtotime($deptime), $value->getLat(), $value->getLng());
            $sunsettime=$sunsetStr['sunset'];
                if ($deptime >date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $sunsettime)) {
                    $nightmin++;
                } else{
                    $totalnightmin='0';
                }
             $deptime ->modify('+1 minutes');  
         }
```

Code posted may not be functional as I've changed variable names, removed other code, it's just to give you an idea of the logic I'm using. Is this even the right approach to go about doing what I am trying to do? I am trying to get something like this working:

http://www.crewlogbook.com/utilities/night_calculator.php

Comment: Using UTC with the sunset times for the 4 seasons then increment or decrement those times for diffferent timezones. Once you have this you can adjust the time based on your flight data.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, how do I get the sunset times for the 4 seasons?

Comment: https://www.timeanddate.com/sun/@4371137 try getting the sunset times for a real time zone then compare midnight UTC to + or - how many hours there are in that real timezone at midnight then + or - the hours for sunset and that should give you UTC sunset times. Only issue is this will not be very accurate as let's say the beginning of Autumn sunset maybe be an hour difference between the end of Autumn sunset. Hope I helped.

Comment: Ah, I am starting to understand what you mean now. I'll give it a go, thanks I appreciate your help :)